# Getting macbook to sleep rather than just dim

Tags: macbook-pro, network, battery, sleep-wake

- Macbook Pro mid-2014
- MacOS 11.4 Big Sur

MacOS appears to have gotten rid of the energy saver preference and relies only on battery settings now. Rather than explicitly stating how long before the laptop sleeps, it now only allows a setting to be changed for when the display will turn off.

I believe that usually the laptop will sleep in due course, after turning off, and Apple has decided this is better for the system to decide after the screen dims rather than the user. Just an assumption though.

#### The issue

My laptop screen will dim after the requested time, but usually won't sleep for several hours after this. I can still ping it and it is active on the network despite being set to not power nap, which specifically disables this kind of activity.

If I manually choose sleep from the menu, it sleeps instantly and I cannot ping it. So it is quite capable of sleeping. It just won't do so automatically.

I have a USB hub plugged in but no drives or anything that should require keeping the laptop disturbed. It's not possible to unplug this but, anyway, if it sleeps manually, I don't see why it's incapable of doing so automatically.

---

### Update

**Activity Monitor** Preventing Sleep tab suggests the following as *Yes*

- sharingd
- WindowServer
- pmset

Running `pmset -g assertions` in terminal prints:

```
Listed by owning process:
   pid 590(sharingd): [0x00110f5000019f5f] 00:00:03 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Handoff"  
   pid 57973(pmset): [0x00035cb00001a659] 509:21:38 NoIdleSleepAssertion named: "pmset prevent sleep"  
   pid 161(WindowServer): [0x00110deb00099f25] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:1000df697 name:AppleUserHIDEventSe product:Keyboard K380 eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 1200 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
Kernel Assertions: 0xc=USB,BT-HID
   id=506  level=255 0x4=USB creat=25/08/2021, 12:28 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14100000 owner=4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
   id=510  level=255 0x4=USB creat=25/08/2021, 12:31 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14110000 owner=4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
   id=761  level=255 0x4=USB creat=15/09/2021, 09:17 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14500000 owner=4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
   id=763  level=255 0x4=USB creat=15/09/2021, 09:24 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14510000 owner=4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
   id=834  level=255 0x8=BT-HID creat=21/09/2021, 09:47 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=IOBluetoothHIDDriver
   id=841  level=255 0x8=BT-HID creat=21/09/2021, 16:24 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=IOBluetoothHIDDriver
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

---

### Update 2

On both of the following occasions, the screen turned off after the time expected (set in system preferences) but the system did not sleep.

`pmset -g log` record 1

```
2021-09-21 20:39:16 +0100 Assertions            [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-21 20:39:17 +0100 Notification          Display is turned off                                                                 
2021-09-21 20:39:17 +0100 Assertions            PID 57973(pmset) Summary NoIdleSleepAssertion "pmset prevent sleep" 513:41:20 id:0x0x10000a659 [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-21 20:39:31 +0100 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: -None-          
2021-09-21 20:39:31 +0100 Assertions            [System: PrevIdle BGTask]          
2021-09-21 20:44:59 +0100 Notification          Next immediate inactivity window start:'2021-09-21 21:00:00 +0100' end:'2021-09-21 21:45:00 +0100'            
2021-09-21 20:45:47 +0100 Assertions            PID 58415(AddressBookSourceSync) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Address Book Source Sync" 00:00:30  id:0x0x100008156 [System: PrevIdle BGTask]          
2021-09-21 20:45:47 +0100 Assertions            PID 507(UserEventAgent) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.AddressBook.ScheduledSync" 00:00:30  id:0x0xb0000815b [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-21 20:54:17 +0100 Assertions            PID 57973(pmset) Summary NoIdleSleepAssertion "pmset prevent sleep" 513:56:20 id:0x0x10000a659 [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-21 21:09:17 +0100 Assertions            PID 57973(pmset) Summary NoIdleSleepAssertion "pmset prevent sleep" 514:11:20 id:0x0x10000a659 [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-21 21:15:59 +0100 Assertions            PID 125(apsd) Released ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-recreatecourierstate-push.apple.com" 00:00:10  id:0x0xb00008212 [System: PrevIdle BGTask]          
2021-09-21 21:24:17 +0100 Assertions            PID 57973(pmset) Summary NoIdleSleepAssertion "pmset prevent sleep" 514:26:19 id:0x0x10000a659 [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-21 21:25:14 +0100 Assertions            PID 507(UserEventAgent) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.mediaanalysisd.fullanalysis" 00:00:38  id:0x0xb00008259 [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-21 21:29:30 +0100 Assertions            PID 161(WindowServer) Created UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:1000df697 name:AppleUserHIDEventSe product:Keyboard K380 eventType:3" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008278 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-09-21 21:29:30 +0100 Notification          Display is turned on                                                                  
2021-09-21 21:29:30 +0100 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler          
2021-09-21 21:29:33 +0100 Assertions            PID 164(loginwindow) Created UserIsActive "Loginwindow User Activity" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008279 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-09-21 21:29:33 +0100 Assertions            PID 164(loginwindow) Released UserIsActive "Loginwindow User Activity" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008279 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          

Total Sleep/Wakes since boot:268

2021-09-21 21:29:51 +0100 : Showing all currently held IOKit power assertions
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 57973(pmset): [0x00035cb00001a659] 514:31:54 NoIdleSleepAssertion named: "pmset prevent sleep"  
   pid 161(WindowServer): [0x001157f600098278] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:1000df697 name:AppleUserHIDEventSe product:Keyboard K380 eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 1199 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
Kernel Assertions: 0xc=USB,BT-HID
   id=506  level=255 0x4=USB creat=25/08/2021, 12:28 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14100000 owner=4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
   id=510  level=255 0x4=USB creat=25/08/2021, 12:31 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14110000 owner=4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
   id=761  level=255 0x4=USB creat=15/09/2021, 09:17 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14500000 owner=4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
   id=763  level=255 0x4=USB creat=15/09/2021, 09:24 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14510000 owner=4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
   id=834  level=255 0x8=BT-HID creat=21/09/2021, 09:47 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=IOBluetoothHIDDriver
   id=844  level=255 0x8=BT-HID creat=21/09/2021, 21:29 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=IOBluetoothHIDDriver
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

`pmset -g log` record 2

```
2021-09-22 11:10:59 +0100 Assertions            PID 161(WindowServer) Summary UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:1000e49c2 name:AppleUserHIDEventSe product:BM30X mouse eventType:17" 00:19:38  id:0x0x9000086d5 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-09-22 11:11:20 +0100 Assertions            PID 161(WindowServer) TimedOut UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:1000e49c2 name:AppleUserHIDEventSe product:BM30X mouse eventType:17" 00:19:59  id:0x0x9000086d5 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-09-22 11:11:21 +0100 Notification          Display is turned off                                                                 
2021-09-22 11:11:21 +0100 Assertions            PID 57973(pmset) Summary NoIdleSleepAssertion "pmset prevent sleep" 528:13:23 id:0x0x10000a659 [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-22 11:11:35 +0100 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: -None-          
2021-09-22 11:11:35 +0100 Assertions            [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-22 11:24:20 +0100 Assertions            PID 371(mds_stores) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.metadata.mds_stores.power" 00:00:28  id:0x0xb0000880a [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-22 11:25:14 +0100 Assertions            PID 60202(AddressBookSourceSync) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Address Book Source Sync" 00:00:30  id:0x0x100008811 [System: PrevIdle BGTask]          
2021-09-22 11:25:14 +0100 Assertions            PID 507(UserEventAgent) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.AddressBook.ScheduledSync" 00:00:30  id:0x0xb00008815 [System: PrevIdle BGTask]          
2021-09-22 11:26:21 +0100 Assertions            PID 57973(pmset) Summary NoIdleSleepAssertion "pmset prevent sleep" 528:28:23 id:0x0x10000a659 [System: PrevIdle]          
2021-09-22 11:27:42 +0100 Assertions            PID 161(WindowServer) Created UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:1000e4151 name:AppleUserHIDEventSe product:Keyboard K380 eventType:3" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008855 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-09-22 11:27:42 +0100 Notification          Display is turned on                                                                  
2021-09-22 11:27:42 +0100 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler          
2021-09-22 11:27:52 +0100 Assertions            PID 164(loginwindow) Created UserIsActive "Loginwindow User Activity" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008865 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-09-22 11:27:52 +0100 Assertions            PID 164(loginwindow) Released UserIsActive "Loginwindow User Activity" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008865 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          

Total Sleep/Wakes since boot:269

2021-09-22 11:29:12 +0100 : Showing all currently held IOKit power assertions
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 1
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 161(WindowServer): [0x001171c500098855] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:1000e4151 name:AppleUserHIDEventSe product:Keyboard K380 eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 1199 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 57973(pmset): [0x00035cb00001a659] 528:31:14 NoIdleSleepAssertion named: "pmset prevent sleep"  
   pid 125(apsd): [0x0011721e000b8869] 00:00:00 ApplePushServiceTask named: "com.apple.apsd-datareceived-push.apple.com"  
Kernel Assertions: 0xc=USB,BT-HID
   id=506  level=255 0x4=USB creat=25/08/2021, 12:28 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14100000 owner=4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
   id=510  level=255 0x4=USB creat=25/08/2021, 12:31 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14110000 owner=4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
   id=761  level=255 0x4=USB creat=15/09/2021, 09:17 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14500000 owner=4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
   id=763  level=255 0x4=USB creat=15/09/2021, 09:24 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14510000 owner=4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
   id=845  level=255 0x8=BT-HID creat=22/09/2021, 09:57 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=IOBluetoothHIDDriver
   id=848  level=255 0x8=BT-HID creat=22/09/2021, 11:45 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=IOBluetoothHIDDriver
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

Comment: Will it sleep if you unplug the hub? If that is the case maybe time for a hub that won't keep your Mac awake

Comment: This is not due to the Battery preferences renaming. Note that it still says "Turn display *off* after:" above the slider. I don't know what's happening for you, but just figured I'd let you know it's something else.

Comment: @EzekielElin Sorry, by dimming, I was implying turning off. I should have stated turning off. I've corrected this now.

Comment: Activity Monitor -> Energy tab has a column "Preventing sleep" maybe it'll list something?

Comment: @biscuitstack Ah, understood. Yes, it is true that (both in the past and currently) the sleep option is distinct and not presented here.

Comment: You can see a list of reasons that idle sleep is prevented with `pmset -g assertions`. You can see a historical log of sleep & wake events and policy decisions with `pmset -g log`. It would be illuminating if you included a relevant excerpt from the log in your question during a time period when you would expect idle sleep but in fact the system remained awake.

Comment: @rogerdpack I've updated the question to reflect this suggestion. I wasn't aware of it before, thanks

Comment: @pion - as above with rogerdpack, thanks also to you.

Comment: @biscuitstack Specifically can you share the output of `pmset-g log` (just the relevant portion of it) after letting the machine idle long enough that it should have slept? I want to see the sleep policy decisions being made.

Comment: I assume it's not plugged in? (under preferences -> battery -> power adapter there's an option to "not sleep when display is off"...)

Comment: @rogerdpack It's plugged in and that option is unchecked, as well as power nap enabling and WOL.

Comment: Is something calling pmset? You can see the process tree in activity monitor ref: https://squeezebox172.rssing.com/chan-4720146/all_p10.html